# Relevance of electromagnetic multipole transitions

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, solid-state-physics, antennas, multipole-expansion

In what kind of systems higher electromagnetic multipole transitions (like electric quadrupole transitions) become important or at least measurable?

Is it for antennas in radiofrequency? Is it in the electronic transitions of atoms, molecules, semiconductors? Is it some x-ray nuclear transition?

Why are these transitions measurable at all? Is it just if some state has just this one relaxation channel via a multipole transition so the transition is visible in spontaneous emission, or are there some ways for stimulated absorption/emission of higher multipole transitions?

Answer (score 0):

In deformed nuclei (with quadrupole deformation) the radiation between states in a rotational band is quadrupole in nature.  Indeed transitions strengths are used to infer the size of the quadrupole deformation.  See for instance [this recent arXiv preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.00102) for some details.